# Running RViZ through X forwarding on headless machine

Tags: ros, rviz, remote, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there possibility to run RViZ remotely on headless machine using X forwarding (ssh -X)? The problem is that remote machine (server) doesn't have graphic card with OpenGL support so, there is MESA installed. For instance, glxgears runs, but RViZ crashes (Segmentation fault) as well as [Gazebo (GLXBadDrawable)](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5387/gazebo-on-headless-simulation-server/). Of course that I can overcome this by running RViZ locally but I would like to avoid ROS installation on client's machine. Thanks for any hint.

gdb output:

```
0x00007fffed1cacc0 in xcb_glx_get_string_string_length () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0
```

Not sure if it's useful but this is OGRE log:

```
user@server:~$ rosrun rviz rviz -l
[ INFO] [1391509162.077619455]: rviz version 1.10.11
[ INFO] [1391509162.077696555]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1391509162.252864686]: Creating resource group General
[ INFO] [1391509162.253011606]: Creating resource group Internal
[ INFO] [1391509162.253083959]: Creating resource group Autodetect
[ INFO] [1391509162.253261229]: SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.253635593]: Registering ResourceManager for type Material
[ INFO] [1391509162.253741639]: Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
[ INFO] [1391509162.253842063]: Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
[ INFO] [1391509162.253959093]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254067107]: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254141490]: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254212287]: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254286650]: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
[ INFO] [1391509162.254383290]: ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254463624]: ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.254534294]: DDS codec registering
[ INFO] [1391509162.254627777]: FreeImage version: 3.15.1
[ INFO] [1391509162.254700004]: This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
[ INFO] [1391509162.255010967]: Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,sti
[ INFO] [1391509162.255109654]: Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
[ INFO] [1391509162.255292757]: Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
[ INFO] [1391509162.255784287]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.255873534]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.255957217]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.256032137]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.256106037]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.256178920]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
[ INFO] [1391509162.256392527]: *-*-* OGRE Initialising
[ INFO] [1391509162.256471531]: *-*-* Version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1391509162.256558108]: Loading library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/RenderSystem_GL
[ INFO] [1391509162.260000802]: Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
[ INFO] [1391509162.260118772]: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
[ INFO] [1391509162.370099950]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1391509162.370207907]: Loading library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/Plugin_OctreeSceneManager
[ INFO] [1391509162.372636195]: Installing plugin: Octree & Terrain Scene Manager
[ INFO] [1391509162.372726792]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1391509162.372792058]: Loading library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/Plugin_ParticleFX
[ INFO] [1391509162.375148443]: Installing plugin: ParticleFX
[ INFO] [1391509162.375246163]: Particle Emitter Type 'Point' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375330569]: Particle Emitter Type 'Box' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375422779]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ellipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375501989]: Particle Emitter Type 'Cylinder' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375565759]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ring' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375643676]: Particle Emitter Type 'HollowEllipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375720116]: Particle Affector Type 'LinearForce' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375789133]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375857933]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader2' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.375929633]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourImage' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376001369]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourInterpolator' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376072513]: Particle Affector Type 'Scaler' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376146796]: Particle Affector Type 'Rotator' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376219213]: Particle Affector Type 'DirectionRandomiser' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376339725]: Particle Affector Type 'DeflectorPlane' registered
[ INFO] [1391509162.376376121]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1391509162.376436528]: CPU Identifier & Features
[ INFO] [1391509162.376471852]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [1391509162.376502120]:  *   CPU ID: GenuineIntel: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
[ INFO] [1391509162.376534838]:  *      SSE: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376561875]:  *     SSE2: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376591423]:  *     SSE3: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376620405]:  *      MMX: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376648209]:  *   MMXEXT: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376676722]:  *    3DNOW: no
[ INFO] [1391509162.376706588]:  * 3DNOWEXT: no
[ INFO] [1391509162.376734837]:  *     CMOV: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376764088]:  *      TSC: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376792375]:  *      FPU: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376822452]:  *      PRO: yes
[ INFO] [1391509162.376852476]:  *       HT: no
[ INFO] [1391509162.376880532]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [1391509162.376911617]: ******************************
*** Starting GLX Subsystem ***
******************************
[ INFO] [1391509162.377003551]: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreWindow(0)", 1x1 windowed  miscParams: externalGLControl= macAPI=carbon parentWindowHandle=96468993 
[ INFO] [1391509162.380447480]: GLXWindow::create used FBConfigID = 261
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

UPDATE:

It works somehow! I just replaced `libgl1-mesa-dri` with `libgl1-mesa-swx11` and now it's possible to run RViz remotely - ssh compression is really necessary :) FPS on local machine is around 10 which is better than nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125861/running-rviz-through-x-forwarding-on-headless-machine/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-04**:
If this is just for a demo, consider using a remote desktop solution— eg, VNC, TeamViewer, etc.

If necessary, run a secondary non-headless machine alongside the robot to host the rviz desktop for the client to connect to.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thanks for hint. But as far as I know VNC has problem with transferring OpenGL windows - am I right?

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-02-20**:
This is not a real solution, but you could also consider setup something with Robot Web Tools (http://robotwebtools.org), that would only require a browser on the client side. A fully-fledged rviz is to my knowledge not yet available, though quite a few building blocks are there already.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-23**:
Using web RViz would be awesome! But as you said - there is no fully-fledged solution. We will probably try to integrate components into one RViz-like solution but it will take (lot of) time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To visualise data and interact with nodes through RViz you don't need to run it on the machine running your roscore, as long as the machine running RViz is able to connect to the master on your headless machine. You basically setup a two machine ROS network, with only RViz on your desktop (fi). All the other nodes can run on your headless machine.

---

> Of course that I can overcome this by running RViZ locally but I would like to avoid ROS installation on client's machine.

Hm, rereading your question: am I correct in understanding that you don't want to install RViz on another machine? In that case, sorry for the noise.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thanks for answer. Well, I know this but I would like to avoid ROS installation on client's machine (if possible). It's intended as development machine for students, workshops etc. which should shield users from need of installing ROS... So this is why remote access is preferred.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-04**:
Yes, you're right. The goal is to have 100% remote access without local installation. But it seems to be bit problematic. Np, thanks anyway for your interest :)